# Segue not updated inside TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

Good afternoon,

I have created a Segue in my `TableViewController` where the user can touch the user profile and it sends that username to a `ProfileViewController`, where the user information is loaded (posts, image, info...) (something like a Facebook wall).

The problem is when I touch one user, it displays everything correctly, but when I touch another profile image, it displays the same `ProfileViewController` again, like the username is not updated and it's send wrong.

When I touch anywhere on the screen and then I touch again the user profile, in that case it works, but I need to make this work in every case.

I'm going to post my `TableViewController` if that helps you to find the problem because it's almost working, the only thing that I need to fix is that username that is not updated (**Tap Gesture Recognizer** over the image).

*The segues are at the end of the code.*

**TableViewController.m**

```
//
//  CarTableViewController.m
//

#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarTableViewCell.h"
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"
#import "OtherProfileUserViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@implementation CarTableViewController

@synthesize carMakes = _carMakes;
@synthesize carModels = _carModels;
@synthesize carImages = _carImages;

@synthesize likes = _likes;
@synthesize comments = _comments;
@synthesize username = _username;
@synthesize refuser = _refuser;
@synthesize profileImage = _profileImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self fetchJson];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Initialize the refresh control.
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    //self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(fetchJson)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_jsonArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    cell.likes.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"likes"];
    cell.comments.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"];
    cell.username.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    cell.refuser.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user_ref"];

    cell.modelLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];

    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];

    [cell.carImage setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagen"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];

    [cell.profileImage setImageWithURL:imageURL2
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]
                            options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    return cell;
}

-(void)fetchJson {

    self.carModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.carMakes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.carImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.likes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.comments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSError *error;
        [_jsonArray removeAllObjects];
        _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                      error:&error];


            for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
            {
                NSDictionary * jsonObject = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* imagen = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"imagen"];
                [_carImages addObject:imagen];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject2 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* user = [jsonObject2 objectForKey:@"user"];
                [_carMakes addObject:user];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject3 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* date = [jsonObject3 objectForKey:@"date"];
                [_carModels addObject:date];
            }
         NSLog(@"carModels ==> %@", _jsonArray);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            {
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
            }});

        }
    );
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueprofile"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        OtherProfileUserViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueprofile2"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        OtherProfileUserViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    }
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seems the selectedRow maybe not updated. you can use sender to locate the row and get the data.

Comment: I would rather recommend to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method and manually perform the segue from it. This sequence seems to me more stable

Comment: Hi @heximal, can you show me an example? I'm pretty new in Objective-C and I don't know how to do what you are saying. Much appreciated.

Comment: yes, sure, just give me a moment, I'll compose it for you)

Comment: Hi @SolaWing, how can I do that? Can you show me an example? Regards.

Comment: Thanks @heximal, I'm really looking forward it because I'm very close to finish this feature and I want to make it work perfect. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: for example, the segue is triggered by your profile button. this button is a descendant subview of cell, so you can repeat get superview, until get a view which class is cell. the cell is which you want.

Comment: I understand what you are saying @SolaWing, but I need some example written because I'm not an expert with Objective-C...! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is one of the options.
1. Delete all existing segues (segueprofile and segueprofile2)
2. Connect your tableviewcontroller (important: not tableview but controller itself) with your details controller by push-segue and name it segueprofile3
3. Refactor your code in the following manner

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath * selectedIndexPath;

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)anIndexPath {
    self.selectedIndexPath = anIndexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueprofile3" sender:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueprofile3"]) {
        OtherProfileUserViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @heximal, that means when I click on the full row (not only on the profile image) is going to start the Segue to ProfileViewController? I need this to be working only on the image profile (and also on the image name) because I have already a segue using the row tap gesture (it opens this "post" with more information).

Comment: OK, that's not a problem, the most part of this code and IB changes remains actual. All you need is to process tapping on UIImageView and run the same segue. If you have simple flat table structure you can associate UIImageView with indexPath by using tag property which is integer, you can assign it when creating TableCell

Comment: I'm going to try what you are saying, but a little bit help will be much appreciated because as I have already told you, I'm not an expert and everything is very difficult for me at the moment. Can you show me some example with what you are saying? Thanks again @heximal

Comment: yes, sure, just a little bit more time required for me to show it) hold on)

Comment: OK :), Much appreciated @heximal.

Comment: Don't forget about me @heximal. Regards.

Comment: Sorry, a lot of works has fallen on my head, I do remember about you. Will try my best

Answer (score 0):

Another option. Place UIButton control right over avatar UIImageView. Create associated IBOutlet inside your CarTableViewCell class and make outlet connection.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIButton * btnAvatar;
```

Next, modify CarTableViewController code

```
//1. declare new propery
@property (nonatomic, strong) id selectedProfile;

//2. implement future button tap handler
-(IBAction) btnAvatarDidPress:(id) sender {
  int tag = ((UIButton *) sender).tag;
  self.selectedProfile = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:tag];
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueprofile3" sender:nil];
}


//Extend your cellForRowAtIndexPath method
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    cell.btnAvatar.tag = indexPath.row;
... rest of method
}
```

then remove didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and connect btnAvatar Touch Up Inside action to btnAvatarDidPress method inside your controller code.
That's all I hope I've forgot nothing.

Answer (score 0):

here is your example, in prepareForSegue, get the cell which button is in:

```
id v = sender;
while (![(v= v.superView) isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] 
       && v!=nil) ;
if (v==nil) 
  // no ancestor view is cell.
else{
  // now v is the cell.
  NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:v];
  // do the left
}
```